# diagonal replacement in an r correlogram

Tags: r

I am rather new to R. I am trying to replace the main diagonal of a correlogram (that's consisted of ones obviously). I have created the vectors for the the correlogram, and have used the cor() function from the cocron package to create the correlogram. I also created a list with the values that i want instead of the ones in the correlogram, consisted of internal reliabilities of the correlogram vectors.

```
library(cocron)
library(fmsb)
# defining correlated variables
JOB_ins = subset(df,select=c("q9","Rq10_new","q11","q12"))
INT_to_quit = subset(df,select=c("q13","q14","Rq15_new","q16"))
Employability = subset(df,select=c("q17","q18","q19","q20"))
Mobility_pref = subset(df,select=c("Rq21","Rq22","Rq23","Rq24","Rq25"))
Career_self_mgmt = subset(df,select=c("q26","q27","q28","q29","q30"
                                         ,"q31","q32","q33"))


# subsetting dataframes 
x = subset(df,select=c(JOB_ins, INT_to_quit, Employability
                                          ,Mobility_pref,Career_self_mgmt))

#creating a correlation matrix

corrmat = cor(x)

#creating Cronbach Alpha reliabilities vector for diagonal replacement
dlist=list(round(CronbachAlpha(JOB_ins),2),round(CronbachAlpha(Int_to_quit),2)
                           ,round(CronbachAlpha(Employability),2)
                           ,round(CronbachAlpha(Mobility_pref),2)
                           ,round(CronbachAlpha(Career_self_mgmt),2))
#replacing the main diagonal
diag(corrmat)=dlist
```

Doing that I do replace the main diagonal but It seems I also turn my correlogram from a matrix to a vector. Any idea how do I keep that from happening or reverse that?

Answer (score 0):

First, you can use a vector instead of a list, replace `list(round(CronbachAlpha(JOB_ins),2),...)` by `c(round(CronbachAlpha(JOB_ins),2),...)`

Second, you can convert a vector to a matrix easily. Example:
`matrix(c(1,2,3,4), nrow = 2)` will convert the `c(1,2,3,4)` vector into the following 2x2 matrix:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4
```